# Angular: require injected controller from module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use the require function in my custom directives. but i simply cannot make it work. This is what i've got:

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('main', []);
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope){
        var random = Math.random()*10000;
    console.log('init random: ' + random);
    $scope.test = function(controllerName){
        console.log(controllerName + " " + random);
    }
  }]);

  app.directive('myDirective', function(){
    return{
      require: "^MyController",
      link: function(scope, els, attrs, req){
        scope.test('myDirective');
      }
    }
  });
    app.directive('mySecondDirective', function(){
    return{
      require: "^MyController",
      link: function(scope, els, attrs, req){
        scope.test('mySecondDirective');
      }
    }
  });
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="main" ng-controller="MyController">
    <my-directive></my-directive>
    <my-second-directive></my-second-directive>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hr8thyq5/3/

all I get is this error message: Controller 'MyController', required by directive 'myDirective', can't be found!

What else do I have to do to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

**Need to Understand the cause -**

If you want to share the same *instance* of a controller, then you use `require`.

`require` ensures the presence of another directive and then includes its controller as a parameter to the link function. So if you have two directives on one element, your directive can *require* the presence of the other directive and gain access to its controller methods. A common use case for this is to require `ngModel`.

`^require`, with the addition of the caret, checks elements above directive in addition to the current element to try to find the other directive. This allows you to create complex components where "sub-components" can communicate with the parent component through its controller to great effect. Examples could include tabs, where each pane can communicate with the overall tabs to handle switching; an accordion set could ensure only one is open at a time; etc.

In either event, you have to use the two directives together for this to work. `require` is a way of communicating between components.

For Further Understanding Go Here : [enter link description here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Answer (score 0):

The controllers specified in `require` are named [after their directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-), not controller names. The purpose of `require` is to communicate with controller instance (`this`) of relative directive, which will be equal to `req` parameter in link function.

Therefore, it can't be limited to `MyController`. If some abstract `ng-controller` controller should be required (which makes little sense because of the fragility of this condition), then it would be

```
require: "^ngController",
```